# How to map nested projections with native query

Tags: spring, nhibernate-projections, hibernate-native-query

I want to map my query result to `RequestProjection` interface values.
The following code works and return request id and submission date.

I need to return worker name too. I have tried `r.worker_name AS workerName` and `r.worker_name AS worker_name` and `r.worker_name AS worker.name` but none of them works.

How can I select and map worker name?

Query:

```
SELECT r.id AS id, r.submission_date AS submissionDate
From Request r
WHERE r.id = 1
```

Projection:

```
public interface RequestProjection {

    Long getId();

    Long getSubmissionDate();

    Worker getWorker();

    interface Worker {

        String getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this without native query using the constructor expression, read more here [Spring JPA native query with Projection gives "ConverterNotFoundException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500309/spring-jpa-native-query-with-projection-gives-converternotfoundexception/49500406#49500406)