# org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get list of values by using JPA Repository query with below code

```
List<Pair<String,byte[]>> pairs = repository.findList();

@Query(value= "select v.agentid, v.mobilenumber from dispatcher v")
public List<Pair<String,byte[]>> findList();
```

But i am getting below error

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [org.javatuples.Pair<?, ?>]
```

What wrong in my logic?

I am using below jar

```
compile group: 'org.javatuples', name: 'javatuples', version: '1.2'
```

Comment: it seems that Hibernate not have a converter to what you want to do, its better to make this conversation when you extract the information from DB

Comment: @YCF_L  i tried with native query also but same issue getting

Comment: Hi, its not related with native or not

Comment: I think problem is lying in your query in repository. This guy had the same problem as you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500309/spring-jpa-native-query-with-projection-gives-converternotfoundexception