# How to take data from crosstabs from Database related ManyToMany relationship using Spring Boot / Thymeleaf

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

There are two tables Books and Users. They are connected by a many-to-many relationship and have a crosstab between them with columns book_id, reader_id, start date, and end date. I need to take data from this table as User.login, Books.title, start_date and end_date. How can I get data from this table if I have the following entities:

Book Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@Column(name = "publishing_year")
private Integer publishingYear;

@Column(name = "sell_cost")
private BigDecimal sellCost;

@Column(name = "rent_cost")
private BigDecimal rentCost;

@Column(name = "amount")
private Integer amount;

//=======Relationships=======

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinTable(name = "rented_books",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "reader_id"))
private List<User> usersRented;
}
```

User Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "wallet")
private Integer wallet;

@Column(name = "enabled")
private boolean enabled;

//=======Relationships=======

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersRented")
private List<Book> rentedBooks;
```

Book Repository

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository  extends CrudRepository<Book,Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT b.title,rb.start_date,rb.expiration_date FROM books b INNER JOIN rented_books rb ON rb.book_id = b.id INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = rb.reader_id WHERE u.id = ?1",nativeQuery = true)
Page<Book> findAllRentedBookByUser(Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

}

But this query doesn't work, throws this error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.

Although in DBMS this query works fine

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the `Book` entity so you need to select all fields for that entity. You can't return a partially filled entity, because JPA does not support partial entity population from native queries.

According to [JPA specification](https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf?AuthParam=1653090384_518f973a15bea3b9b4f83107b6d213a1):

> 3.10.16.1 Returning Managed Entities from Native Queries
>
> When an entity is to be returned from a native query, the SQL
> statement should select all of the columns that are mapped to the
> entity object. This should include foreign key columns to related
> entities. The results obtained when insufficient data is available are
> undefined

**Example of correct query:**

```java
@Repository
public interface BookRepository  extends CrudRepository<Book,Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT b.* FROM books b INNER JOIN rented_books rb ON rb.book_id = b.id INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = rb.reader_id WHERE u.id = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Book> findAllRentedBookByUser(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

In case you want to return a custom column set you need to create an additional simple POJO class and define a mapping for it.

Example: [How to fix convertion error in Nativequery in Spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72287093/how-to-fix-convertion-error-in-nativequery-in-spring-boot/72297115#72297115)

**1. Create a custom POJO class**

```java
import java.util.Date;

public class BookDetails {
   private String title;
   private Date start_date;
   private Date expiration_date;

   public BookDetails(String title, Date start_date, Date expiration_date) {
        this.title = title;
        this.start_date = start_date;
        this.expiration_date = expiration_date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public Date getStart_date() {
        return this.start_date;
    }

    public Date getExpiration_date() {
        return this.expiration_date;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setStart_date(Date start_date) {
        this.start_date = start_date;
    }

    public void setExpiration_date(Date expiration_date) {
        this.expiration_date = expiration_date;
    }
}
```

**2. Define @NamedNativeQuery and mapping for POJO class**

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@NamedNativeQuery(name ="BookDetailsByUser",
        query =
                " SELECT b.title, rb.start_date, rb.expiration_date " +
                " FROM books b INNER JOIN rented_books rb ON rb.book_id = b.id INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = rb.reader_id " +
                " WHERE u.id = ?1 ",
        resultSetMapping = "BookDetailsMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="BookDetailsMapping",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(targetClass = BookDetails.class,
                        columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "title"),
                                   @ColumnResult(name = "start_date"),
                                   @ColumnResult(name = "expiration_date")
                        })
        })
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "publishing_year")
    private Integer publishingYear;

    @Column(name = "sell_cost")
    private BigDecimal sellCost;

    @Column(name = "rent_cost")
    private BigDecimal rentCost;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private Integer amount;

//=======Relationships=======

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH,CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinTable(name = "rented_books",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "reader_id"))
    private List<User> usersRented;
}
```

**3. Use named query in repository**

```java
@Repository
public interface BookRepository  extends CrudRepository<Book,Long> {
    @Query(name = "BookDetailsByUser", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<BookDetails> findBookDetailsByUser(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: gives this error 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: books is not mapped

Comment: Please ensure that you are working with native query, not JPQL. Use `@NamedNativeQuery` annotation and `nativeQuery = true` flag. You can copy one to one from my proposed manual

Comment: I copied everything you wrote

Comment: Please share the full stack trace of the exception. I think you are using HQL query instead of native SQL, it is from the error part that you provided `org.hibernate.hql`

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Books is not mapped
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:169) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.0.Final.jar:5.6.0.Final]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.0.Final.jar:5.6.0.Final]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.0.Final.jar:5.6.0.Final]
 at

Comment: Probably this will be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23018836/org-hibernate-hql-internal-ast-querysyntaxexception-table-is-not-mapped

Comment: If you can provide some reproducible example I will help you. Edit question or share github link with minimal code. Current answer is working properly, I have rechecked it locally before posting.